# Remove all characters existing between first n occurences of a specific character in each line in shell

Tags: shell, unix, sed

Say I have txt file with characters as follows:

```
   abcd|123|kds|Name|Place|Phone
   ldkdsd|323|jkds|Name1|Place1|Phone1
```

I want to remove all the characters in each line that exist within first 3 occurences of | character in each line. I want my output as:

```
     Name|Place|Phone
     Name1|Place1|Phone1
```

Could anyone help me figure this out? How can I achieve this using sed?

Answer (score 4):

This would be a typical task for `cut`

```
cut -d'|' -f4- file
```

output:

```
Name|Place|Phone
Name1|Place1|Phone1
```

the `-f4-` means you want from the forth field till the end. Adjust the `4` if you have a different requirement.

Comment: Great!! But how do you use this to change it in the file itself ?

Comment: not a sed but the most efficient (and simple to use/understand) :-)

Comment: @yugesh Use temporary file and redirection. `cut -d'|' -f4- file >tempfile;mv tempfile file` (or a cp by security followed by a rm)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu OP didn't mention he wanted to "in-place" change the file. but Thx for the redirection comment. I would make `;` -> `&&`

Comment: yet once again better solution with the `&&`

Comment: +1 Way to go. Much easier to read than the `sed` answers, and still works if there happen not to be 6 fields - unlike the `awk` solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below sed commad,

```
$ sed -r 's/^(\s*)[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|/\1/g' file
   Name|Place|Phone
   Name1|Place1|Phone1
```

- `^(\s*)` captures all the spaces which are at the start.
- `[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|` Matches  upto the third `|`. So this `abcd|123|kds|` will be matched.
- All the matched characters are replaced by the chars which are present inside the first captured group.

Comment: It works! But how does it work :O ? Could you please explain it to me... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^\([^|]*|\)\{3\}//' file
```

or more readably:

```
sed -r 's/^([^|]*\|){3}//' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\(\([^|]*|\)\{3\}\)//' YourFile
```

this is a posix version, on GNU sed force `--posix` due to the use of `|` that is interpreted as "OR" and not in posix version.

**Explaination**

Replace the 3 first occurence (`\{3\}`) of [ any charcater but `|` followed by `|` (`\([^|]*|\)`) ] by nothing (`//` that is an empty pattern)

Answer (score 0):

You can print the last 3 fields:

```
awk '{print $(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF}' FS=\| OFS=\| file
Name|Place|Phone
Name1|Place1|Phone1
```